# Pyspark not creating SparkContext (Yarn). bad gateway or network traffic blocked?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, cloudera-cdh, cdsw

Here is some context of my installation of pyspark binary.

In my company, we use a Cloudera Data Science Workbench (CDSW). When we create a session for a new projet, I'm guessing it's a image from a specific Dockerfile. And inside this dockerfile is pushed the installation of CDH binaries and configuration.

Now I wish to use thoses configurations outside CDSW. I have a kubernetes cluster where I deploy webapps. And I would like to use spark in Yarn mode to deploy very small ressources for the webapps.

What I have done, is to tar.gz all binaries and config from `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4484.8795072` and `/var/lib/cdsw/client-config/`.
Then untar.gz them in a container or in a WSL2 instance.

Instead of unpacking everything in `/var/` or `/opt/` like I should do, I've put them in `$HOME/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4484.8795072/*` and `$USER/etc/client-config/*`. Why I did this? Because I might want to use a mounted Volume in my kubernetes and share binaries between containers.

I've `sed` and modifiy all configuration files to adapt paths:

- spark-env.sh
- topology.py
- Any *.txt, *.sh, *.py

So I managed to run `beeline` `hadoop` `hdfs` `hbase` pointing them with the `hadoop-conf` folder. I can use `pyspark` but in local mode only. But What I really want is to use `pyspark` with `yarn`.

So I set a bunch of env variables to make this work:

```sh
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HOME/etc/client-config/spark-conf/yarn-conf
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=$HOME/etc/client-config/spark-conf/yarn-conf
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local
export BIN_DIR=$HOME/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4484.8795072/bin
export PATH=$BIN_DIR:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.6
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3.6
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1

export SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4484.8795072/lib/spark
export PYSPARK_ARCHIVES_PATH=$(ZIPS=("$CDH_DIR"/lib/spark/python/lib/*.zip); IFS=:; echo "${ZIPS[*]}"):$PYSPARK_ARCHIVES_PATH
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$HOME/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4484.8795072/lib/hadoop/client/accessors-smart-1.2.jar:<ALL OTHER JARS FOR EVERY BINARIES>
```

Anyway, all of the paths are existing and working. And since I've sed all config files, they also generate the same path as the exported one.

I launch my pyspark binary like this:

```sh
pyspark --conf "spark.master=yarn" --properties-file $HOME/etc/client-config/spark-conf/spark-defaults.conf --verbose
```

FYI, it is using pyspark 2.4.0. And I've install `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)`. The same that I found on the CDSW instance. I added the keystore with the public certificate of the company. And I also generate a keytab for the kerberos auth. Both of them are working since I can used `hdfs` with `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HOME/etc/client-config/hadoop-conf`

In verbose mode I can see all the details and configuration from spark. When I compare it from the CDSW session, they are quite identical (with modified path, for example :

```
Using properties file: /home/docker4sg/etc/client-config/spark-conf/spark-defaults.conf
Adding default property: spark.lineage.log.dir=/var/log/spark/lineage
Adding default property: spark.port.maxRetries=250
Adding default property: spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
Adding default property: spark.driver.log.persistToDfs.enabled=true
Adding default property: spark.yarn.jars=local:/home/docker4sg/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4484.8795072/lib/spark/jars/*,local:/home/docker4sg/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4484.8795072/lib/spark/hive/*
...
```

After few seconds it fails to create a `sparkSession`:

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2022-02-22 14:44:14 WARN  Client:760 - Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
2022-02-22 14:44:14 ERROR SparkContext:94 - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 12: pyspark.zip:
...
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 12: pyspark.zip:
...
2022-02-22 14:44:15 WARN  YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint:69 - Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
2022-02-22 14:44:15 WARN  MetricsSystem:69 - Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
2022-02-22 14:44:15 WARN  SparkContext:69 - Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58
```

From what I understand, it fails for a reason I'm not sure about and then tries to fall back into an other mode. That fails too.

In the configuration file `spark-conf/yarn-conf/yarn-site.xml`, it is specified that it is using a `zookeeper`:

```
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.zk-address</name>
    <value>corporate.machine.node1.name.net:9999,corporate.machine.node2.name.net:9999,corporate.machine.node3.name.net:9999</value>
  </property>
```

Could it be that the Yarn cluster does not accept traffic from a random IP (kuber IP or personnal IP from computer)? For me, the IP i'm working on is not on the whitelist, but at the moment I cannot ask to add my ip to the whitelist. How can I know for sure I'm looking in the good direction?

Edit 1:

As said in the comment, the URI of the `pyspark.zip` was wrong. I've modified my `PYSPARK_ARCHIVES_PATH` to the real location of `pyspark.zip`.

```
PYSPARK_ARCHIVES_PATH=local:$HOME/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4484.8795072/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip,local:$HOME/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4484.8795072/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip
```

Now I get an error `UnknownHostException`:

```sh
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to <HOSTNAME>:13250
...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: <HOSTNAME>
...
```

Comment: You think too much. There's a Java `URISyntaxException` with an error message saying that some configuration property contains `pyspark.zip` or `pyspark.zip:` instead of e.g. `file:///tmp/pyspark.zip` or `hdfs:///user/dummy/pyspark.zip` or `https://service.name/path/spark.zip` -- a syntax error. Back to reality, find out how the containerized Cloudera Data SciFi Workbench manages that ZIP and how that translates in your local setup.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Indeed, the path of PYSPARK_ARCHIVES_PATH was wrong, pointing to a non existing folder. I've hardcoded `PYSPARK_ARCHIVES_PATH` instead of dynamically trying to create it. Now I get `java.net.UnknownHostException: $HOSTNAME`
I'll update my post for proper formating.

Comment: Now you have a networking error that has nothing to do with Spark (apart from any configuration files you have)... `ping` and `nslookup` / `dig` would be used to troubleshoot

Comment: @OneCricketeer What I don't understand is that <HOSTNAME> is my local hostname, not the host name of the zookeeper/Yarn

Comment: Where is the error coming from? The executors need to return data back to the driver (your local machine), so that might be the cause. Have you tried using `--deploy-mode=cluster`?

Comment: The error comes from the command `pyspark --conf "spark.master=yarn"` in verbose + specify conf file. I'll try asap. I can tell that pyspark can acces HDFS since its writting a hidden folder in its user directory.